# Mongo find the max value of an attribute in an array of objects and return the entire matching object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on application having NodeJS on server-side and MongoDB as database and Mongoose as ORM.

Below is my document in mongo collection.

```
{
  "rec_id": 73282,
  "process_id": 73272,
  "is_cancelled": false,
  "process_status_progress": [
    {
      "state": {
        "state_number": 1,
        "state_name": "Step 1"
      },
      "last_update_date": 1499773230587,
      "state_error": {}
    },
    {
      "state": {
        "state_number": 2,
        "state_name": "Step 2"
      },
      "last_update_date": 1499773246295,
      "state_error": {}
    },
    {
      "state": {
        "state_number": 3,
        "state_name": "Step 3"
      },
      "last_update_date": 1499773508526,
      "state_error": {
        "error_message": "Some error message",
        "error_details": {
          "key": "value"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "job_status": "Step 3"
}
```

I am executing below query (which selects documents for which max progress state is less than state number 9):

```
db.processes.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "maxState": {
        "$max": "$process_status_progress.state.state_number"
      },
      "rec_id": 1,
      "process_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "maxState": {
            "$lt": 9
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

This returns me following output:

> {   "rec_id": 1494929214467,   "process_id": 1494929214501,
>   **"maxState": 3** }

"state_error" object will have keys "error_message" and "error_details" if any error is there in that state while processing and "state_error" will not be blank.
Objects will be added into "process_status_progress" as process is processing further. I have just shown sample data above. So document may have more objects in "process_status_progress" array field.

How can I return whole object from `process_status_progress` which is having max value for state number and `state_error` having any data like below?

> {   "rec_id": 1494929214467,   "process_id": 1494929214501,
>   "maxState": 3,   **"maxStateObj": {
>       "state": {
>         "state_number": 3,
>         "state_name": "Step 3"
>       },
>       "last_update_date": 1499773508526,
>       "state_error": { "error_message" : "Some error message", "error_details" : {"key" : "value"}}   }** }

That means I want to fetch documents for which max state (less than provided state number. In this case, it is 9) is having error and fetch that object which is inside "process_status_progress" as well.
Can I achieve this in single Mongo query or I have to fetch data and then write loop for processing that data?

Comment: What do you mean by "state_error" having any data? All items are the same in your sample so it's not sure what you mean. Also the "max" of "state_number" would appear to simply the "last array element". Which means unless there is some reason it should not **always** be that, then you really don't need `$max`, but can simply return "the last element in the array".

Comment: @NeilLunn: "state_error" having any data means if it is having "error_message" and "error_details" keys. It will not be always that max state is "last array element". I have updated question and added more details.
Did you get what I am trying to explain? Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Still very unclear on *"state_error having any data"*. What does that mean?? Is `"state_error": {}` like you have in the samples okay? Or should it have something like `"state_error": { "key": "something" }`? And how are we supposed to know that? Are there "fixed key names" which would appear? Or can it be anything?  Which MongoDB server version do you have available?

Comment: What does not help your question is that as I can best interpret your intentions, none of the data you supply would actually match the conditions you ask for. So it is generally best to display at least one choice of multiple data which "does" actually match the conditions you want. And therefore that would be the result to return. If nothing you show matches, then people ( such as me ) are unsure if if the result you want is the one we pick. If you show it, then we know for sure.

Comment: @NeilLunn : Please check updated question.